# Check if a User has a Game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've done some searching here and I've not been able to find anything that quite answers what I'm looking for. If I failed in my search I apologize.

Moving on, I am new to Rails and I'm working on an application to test the waters if you will. I'm using Devise for authentication and it's proving quite useful. That said, I've run into a big of a road block with where a certain check for data would go, and how I would go about it.

I have three tables: `users`, `games`, and `users_games` (I read that this was an acceptable naming convention for relational tables, correct me if I'm wrong). On a Games page I would like to display a certain message if the currently logged in User has this Game added to their account (in `users_games`). I'm unsure of where to perform this check, or if it even matters at all.

As for the actual checking, my initial idea would be something along the lines of:

games_controller.rb

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  def show
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @user_owns = UsersGames.where(:game_id => @game.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Then on the view checking if `@user_owns` has a value or not.

Thanks in advance for any insight or wisdom you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this way, may be you don't need users_games
if game has_many users and user belongs_to game

```
  def show
    @game = Game.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  end
```

Then on the view checking if @game has a value or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Users<->Games` relationship is a simple HABTM with no additional attributes on the join table, i.e.

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games

class Game < AR::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

you don't need to have a separate model for the join table, provided that you follow the Rails naming convention that requires you to follow the lexicographical order when naming your join table, i.e. in your case it would be `games_users`, not the other way around like you have it now.

Going back to your original question, I think it can be as simple as this:

```
def show
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game_owned = current_user.games.include? @game
end
```

You can also make this a method on your User model:

```
class User < AR::Base
  ...
  def owns_game?(game)
    self.games.include?(game)
  end
end
```

and then call `current_user.owns_game?(@game)` in your controllers/views.